# Distribution of $X+X^2$ if $X$ has PDF $6e^{-2x}$ on $-k\le x\le k$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Take the random variable $X$ with distribution
$$f_X(x) = 6e^{-2x}, -k \leq x \leq k.$$
I want to find the distribution of $X+X^2.$ I believe that the first step of
this is to figure out the $k$ that makes $f_X$ a legal PDF. We see that
$$\int_{-k}^k 6e^{-2x} dx = 6 \int_{-k}^{k} e^{-2x} dx.$$
we see $u = -2x \implies du = -2dx$, and thus
$$=-3 \int_{-k}^{k} e^u du = -3 ( e^{-2x} \mid_{-k}^k)
= -3(e^{-2k} - e^{2k}) = 1$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{-3} = e^{-2k} - e^{2k},$$

and I am having some issues finding the $k$ that makes this correct. Any
recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct all the way through, and just need to consider using a hyperbolic function identity.

Recall that $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and note that

$$6\int_{-k}^k \mathrm{e}^{-2x}\,\mathrm{d}x = -6\left(\frac{e^{-2k}-e^{2k}}{2}\right)= 6\left(\frac{e^{2k}-e^{-2k}}{2}\right)
= 6\sinh(2k)$$

Now, simply solve the equation $6\sinh(2k) = 1$ for $k$.